# HDD problems after reset

Tags: hard-drive, reset

Well, yesterday my computer suddenly started to hang. After a while, I decided to use the reset button. But after that, my system wouldn't boot. When I try to, it skips GRUB2 and directly shows me a Windows boot error (I suspect it's unable to boot from my first HDD, so it tries to boot from the second one. I just didn't know that it was even bootable.)

The BIOS displays both of my HDDs as it always does. But when booting a linux live system, `fdisk -l` only displays my second HDD. (However, I can see in syslog that it finds my HDD, it just doesn't display it). Even /dev/sda exists, but not /dev/sda1,2, and so on. `lshw` also shows my HDD, and it correctly detects the model, size and the serial number. But: According to `lshw`, my second HDD has the capability 'partitioned partitioned:dos' while the first one has not, so I guess my partition table is broken (from a simple reset? Still can't believe it.)

So what can I do? I can't believe my HDD is really 'broken' because I just used a simple reset. I tried to use `testdisk` to restore my partition table. `Testdisk` also detects the HDD, but when I do a quick test, I'm getting a read error for every cylinder it tries to read.

Any ideas? Would be nice if I could recover the data.

Comment: Probably the reset didn't break the HDD but you had to press reset because the HDD crashed...

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, "so I guess my partition table is broken", I would stop trying to use that drive until someone here on superuser.com comes along and provides you with a better assessment.

If the partition table is bad and you want to recover your data, further attempts at reading/writing may result in a loss of data.

Also, the act of hitting reset did not damage the drive. It was likely already damaged and you just didn't notice it until you reset the system.

Comment: 'It was likely already damaged' - Yeah, I guess it was.